# Trying to deserialize variable nested JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I get the JSON code below from a website; 
Unfortunately I cannot control or change this.
The workers part is variable, so it is possible workers are added OR removed. (minimum 1 worker)

You would normally expect the WORKERS part to be a JSON array, but unfortunately it is not.

```
 {
"confirmed_rewards": "0.00000",
"hashrate": 0,
"payout_history": "0.000000000",
"estimated_rewards": 0.0000000,
"workers": {
    "worker.1": {
        "alive": true,
        "hashrate": 1
    },
    "worker.2": {
        "alive": false,
        "hashrate": 0
    }
},
"efficiency": "100.00",
"shares": "0",
"rewardType": "4"}
```

I tried to deserialize the JSON string using the following classes:

```
public class Status
{
    public string confirmed_rewards;
    public int hashrate;
    public string payout_history; 
    public string estimated_rewards;
    public List<Worker> workers;
    public string efficiency;
    public string shares;
    public string rewardType;
}

public class Worker
{
    public WorkerStatus Status;
}

public class WorkerStatus
{
    public bool alive;
    public int hashrate;
}
```

Unfortunately that just gives me the error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into 
type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Worker]' because the type requires a
JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

I'm really curious if there is a good way of deserializing this.
Remember; the number (and names!) of workers CAN change! So just making a hardcoded class named worker.1 is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried changing definition to array?  i.e. instead of `List<Worker> workers;` declare as `Worker[] workers;`

Comment: Deserialize to a map?

Comment: @LB2 that won't solve the problem. The issue i that `workers` is an object and not an array. I recommend reading the properties of `workers` into a dictionary where the key is the instance name and the value is the `Worker` object. This may require to create a custom serializer, not positive about that but I guarantee you there is sufficient information to solve the problem in the json.NET docs.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply, The solution by LB did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `worker.n` is not a valid property name and can change with the number of workers, declare *workers* as `Dictionary<string, Worker>`

```
var workers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status>(json);
```

---

```
public class Worker
{
    public bool alive { get; set; }
    public int hashrate { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string confirmed_rewards { get; set; }
    public int hashrate { get; set; }
    public string payout_history { get; set; }
    public double estimated_rewards { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Worker> workers { get; set; }
    public string efficiency { get; set; }
    public string shares { get; set; }
    public string rewardType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like:

```
Status datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status>(jsonstring);
```

You would need to make your worker a Dictionary for this as well

```
public Dictionary<string, Worker> workers { get; set; }
```

This is using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Dictionary indeed was the way to go :)